# JSON Representation of HashMap

Tags: java, json, hashmap

what is the Json representation of `HashMap<String, String>`?

I have tried this way but getting bad request error.

```
"userPreferences":{{"mobile":"yes"},{"email":"yes"}}
```

Comment: Which language's `HashMap` are you talking about? Which serialization framework are you using? How do you build the `HashMap`? What output are you expecting? This question is far too broad and unresearched as it stands, and will likely get closed without further details.

Comment: I'm talkning about Java HashMap

Comment: Seems like Java, how about `[{"mobile":"yes"}, ..]`

Comment: Tried but not working :(

Answer (score 21):

It should be like this

```
{ "userPreferences":{"mobile":"yes","email":"yes"} }
```

Answer (score 10):

```
"userPreferences":{"mobile":"yes","email":"yes"}
```

Comment: sweet :) so first correct answer, no green tickmark?

Answer (score 3):

The JSON you have would be invalid even as a JavaScript object, since you haven't defined property names for the two "inner" objects. A `HashMap` is basically a set of key-value pairs. Your JSON should look like:

```
"userPreferences": {
    "mobile": "yes",
    "email": "yes"
}
```